# Move View Up When Scrolling Listview in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have below layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/generic_toolbar_height"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/cordinator"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="@color/add_item_header_bg"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_shirt" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/generic_fotter"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Where in viewPager the fragment is inserted and that fragments contains only listview .

**My Issue**  : I want the Image HeaderImage and TabLayout to scrool up on scrool of listview , but when i tried to detect scroll of listview and make the headerImage and tabLyaout gone the listview again got reset and hence position 0 is detected in scrolview hence the image and lablayout never moves up any alternative for this please suggest below is screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with CollapsingToolbar??

Comment: but i want complete lablayout and image hidden on scroll up on listview scrrol not only toolbar

Comment: Yes, but I intend to incorporate the image view in collapsingtoolbar doing so would scroll upward, then with the animation you can also collapsing TableLayout

Comment: ok let me try on that , not sure how collapsing toolbar works

Comment: Try and let me know, otherwise we should try to collapse layout programmatically on listview scroll

Comment: Think this is what you are looking for. https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager

Comment: yes right the above link replicates what i m looking for but right now i had partiall solved issue via collapse toolbar now what is happning is when i scrool listview up the collapsingtoolbar isnt moving up instead i had to scrool upside manully .

Comment: @MicheleLacorte Thx your solution woked

Comment: Well! Can I put the answer now

Comment: @MicheleLacorte Yes Plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to incorporate the image view in `CollapsingaToolbar` doing so would scroll upward, then with the `animation` you can also collapsing `TableLayout`

Comment: thx , could you look over this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312286/scrollview-not-scrolling-to-most-bottom

Answer (score 1):

This is a library which help you to move the  view up, when you scroll. 
 github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager .

Comment: thx its full solution but currenlty without changing code @Michele Locorte solution worked