# ScrollView not scrolling to most bottom

Tags: android, scrollview

I have layout like below :

[image]

Here the ScrollView contains many element.

**My Issue**  : The fotter layout as shown in above layout is initally gone and on checkbox click i m showing and hidding on bottom on scrollview . When i make it visible it gets visbile on bottom of all items but when i scroll to bottom progratically it not scrollling to fullest

```
mCkAddEssence.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                LinearLayout fotter=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fotter);

                if(isChecked==true)
                {
                    fotter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ScrollView scrool=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
                    scrool.smoothScrollTo(0, scrool.getBottom());

                }else
                {
                    fotter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

            }
        });
```

Tried on Child Element :

```
 fotter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 ScrollView scrool=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
 scrool.scrollTo(0,mCkAddEssence.getBottom());
```

but not worked.

Comment: The ScrollView not "encompasses" all your LinearLayout ??

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getBottom()), `View#getBottom()` returns position relative to its parent.

You are calling `getBottom()` on the ScrollView but IMO you should call it in ScrollView's first (and the only one) child.